# Bash script delete files older than n days ago based on the timestamp in filename?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find

I have some logs files with

```
 somefiles.log.YYYY-mm-dd
```

and I want to delete those files that are older than N days base on the timestamp in its filename.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to google similar example. But what I need is something that works within the filename, not the creation or modified timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

use *cut* command to retrieve YYYY-MM-dd part of filename. and use *date* command as following to convert it to time_t type.

> date -d "YYYY-MM-dd" +%s

then you can compare time_t to determine which file should be deleted.

Comment: Agreed.
Could also potentially think about using -iregex on find.

Comment: @Eduardo, Thank you for reminding me of Matcher Selection in find comand.(I do not know it before). but It seems difficult to calculate date in regexp.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, would be annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Better delete based on creation time using find:

```
find /var/log/ -name somefiles.log.* -ctime +3 -delete
```

Comment: I've seen similar answers. But in this case, I want it to work within the filename, not the creation or modified timestamp.